# Add new node to existing nodes through XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to retain few values in XML and need to add new nodes through XSLT.

Value needs to be retained and new option needs to be added.

How to achieve this. Below is my code.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datas>
  <data key="key1">    
    <value>a</value>
    <options>
      <option>a</option>
      <option>b</option>
      <option>c</option>
    </options>
  </data>
  <data key="key2">    
    <value>z</value>
    <options>
      <option>x</option>
      <option>y</option>
      <option>z</option>
    </options>
  </data>
</datas>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="datas">
    <datas>
      <data key="key1">        
        <value>
          <xsl:value-of select="/datas/data[key = 'key1']/value" />
        </value>
        <options>
          <option>a</option>
          <option>b</option>
          <option>c</option>
          <option>d</option>
        </options>
      </data>
      <data key="key2">       
        <value>
          <xsl:value-of select="/datas/data[key = 'key2']/value" />
        </value>
        <options>
          <option>x</option>
          <option>y</option>
          <option>z</option>
        </options>
      </data>
    </datas>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`<option>d</option>` is not getting added.

can someone help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="/datas/data[key = 'key1']/value" />
   ```

   you need:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="/datas/data[@key = 'key1']/value" />
   ```

---

2. > `<option>d</option>` is not getting added.

   I cannot reproduce the problem, using your code:
   http://xsltransform.net/94rmq5E

---

3. You could have made this much simpler:

   **XSLT 1.0**

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="data[@key='key1']/options">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
           <option>d</option>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

Comment: sorry that was typo error, i corrected in the question. My problem is how to add new option now.

Comment: @user007 What new option? Please edit your question and show us the expected result.